# Is it possible to run Django and Wordpress on same server with selective urls with apache?

Tags: django, wordpress, apache

Is it possible to run Django and Wordpress on the same server? I have seen other examples where its possible if / is handled by django and /blog/ by wordpress but how about

```
/api/ -- eg. api/v1/user/show
/signin/,
/create/,
/dashboard/ -- eg. dashboard/reports/
```

By Django and

```
/
/about/
/security/
/contact/
/tos/
/privacy/
/faq/
/contact/
```

etc with Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as far as I know if you're using nginx and uwsgi, you can config nginx like this:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/path/to/your/django/project/your.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    location /about{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;# where your wordpress run
    }
    location /secirity{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;# where your wordpress run
    }
    # other url needed to handle by wordpress

    # left are all handled by django
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /path/to/your/django/project/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using apache. Any idea about that ?

Comment: @Jonathan apache also has the same config, you can search about `proxy`. May be this 'http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html' is helpful

Comment: Thanks shellbye. I am looking into it further but my limited knowledge in server config makes it more challenging

Comment: @Jonathan I am not familiar with apache, if you are using nginx I sure can offer some more help.